# Updating values of dynamically created nested UI elements C#

Tags: c#, uwp, observablecollection

I am new to UWP and C# but I have been tasked with creating a UI that is created dynamically based on an XML file that is read in.

I am having trouble updating values that are nested inside an ObservableCollection.

The current structure uses StackPanels as a container to add UI elements to. The heirarchy looks like this when the elements are created.

```
StackPanel = Outermost container panel
-StackPanel = Section Stack panel :implements ObservableCollection
--StackPanel = Entry container panel :implements INotifyPropertyChanged
---StackPanel = Entry inner Wrapper panel :implements INotifyPropertyChanged
---- This is where the UI elements like textboxes live
---- TextBox
---- TextBox
```

I need extract the values of the TextBoxes but they don't ever update from their original value.
I am having trouble finding documentation that points to a good way of doing this kind of thing (usually means it shouldn't really be done haaa) any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using databinding on the `TextBox` elements? Make sure `Mode="TwoWay"` is specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this link to solve my problem.
http://www.teixeira-soft.com/bluescreen/2016/03/23/c-how-to-dinamicaly-select-a-datatemplate-for-each-item-in-a-list/

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Read the data from your xml to your ObservableCollection to build a data as base data structure.
2. Use binding to bind it to your UI elements from your ObservableCollection. By the way, as Peter mentioned, make sure you've already made it twoway binding, in that way the changes from your UI will reflect the data store in memory
3. Use some ways(for example use a button) to save changes from your UI and then update and save the data in memory to your original xml file.

Some documention can be found from the following:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart
- Code Sample:https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XmlDocument